# Как присвоить оригинальный массив элементов во Vue

Tags: vue.js

Стоит задача что при нажатии на кнопку нужно вернуть оригинальный список элементов. Но проблема в том что этот оригинальный список становиться реативным тоже, хотя в data его нет. В чём может быть проблема?

```
const newPaymentItemsArr = dataPaymentItems.map((item, index) => {
  return {
    num: index,
        id: item.id,
        field: {
            amount: item.amount,
            fee: item.feeAmount
        },
  }
}

const paymentItemsOriginal = [...newPaymentItemsArr];

const multiplyMethods = new Vue({
    el: '#multiply-methods',
    data() {
        return {
          paymentItems: [...newPaymentItemsArr],
       }
    },

    methods: {
      cancel() {
            this.paymentItems = [];
            this.paymentItems = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(paymentItemsOriginal));
        },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код написан с ошибкой, во-первых, 
.map((item, index) => {
  return {
    num: index,
        id: item.id,
        field: {
            amount: item.amount,
            fee: item.feeAmount
        },
  }
})  <-- поставьте скобку
Во-вторых, dataPaymentItems что это за массив? и почему нельзя сразу его передать в vue component? Скажем через props или import передаём нужный вам массив или объект, дальше у вас в наличии будут исходные данные и делайте с ними всё что хотите выглядит это так в 
        data() {
                return {
                 arr: newArr(dataPaymentItems),
            }
          }, 
methods: {newArr: function(el) {что вам нужно сделать}}
и после этого работать через this:arr для обращения к данным полученным из функции и просто dataPaymentItems для обращения к изначальным данным